# python matplotlib dates are squashed together

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Here is my code:

```
# Graph for both infections and closures

# # plotting the points  
plt.plot(graph_date, graph_daily_infections, label = "Infections per day")
plt.plot(graph_date, graph_total_infections, label = "Infection overall")
plt.plot(graph_date, graph_daily_closure, label = "Closures per day")  
plt.plot(graph_date, graph_total_closure, label = "Closure overall") 
# # naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('Date') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Number of Infections/Closure') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Daily infections and closure overtime \n Infection Rate: {0} | Closure Threshold: {1}'.format(infectionRate,closeThreshold)) 
# show a legend on the plot
plt.legend()
# # changing the scale of the x ticks at the bottom

# # plt.locator_params(nbins=4)

# # set size of the graph
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,15)
# # function to show the plot

plt.show()
```

The problem with this code is that the dates are squashed together on the x axis when they are being displayed. See below:
[image]

Is there a way to only show the months, or to only shows the months and the years ? the interval for which the graph should display the data is for 4 months so showing only the months / year and month would be ideal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `autofmt_xdate()` to auto format the x-axis.

According to [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html), you would have to add this before `plt.show()`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(date, r.close)

# rotate and align the tick labels so they look better
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

And for the months and years, you can add:

```
ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another recipe:

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
 
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
```

[More information about different format options in matplotlib.mdates module](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html).